# Ignore property when assigning a class instance

Tags: c#

I have a method to copy a class model then save it to a database.

```
// get model
var source = FetchModelFactory(id);

//set up clone
DungeonTreasure clone;

// clone
clone = source;

// save to the database
Session.Save(clone);
```

The problem is, it is copying the `id` of the source model.

I need every property except the `id`, I just need that to be null because the database assigns an id.

So I tried this:

```
clone.id = null;
```

But it won't let me do that, because the setter inside the DungeonTreasure class is protected:

```
public virtual Int32 Id { get; protected set; }
```

So is there a way to ignore the `id` when I copy the source to the clone?

Thanks!

Comment: You're doing reference assignment btw, so any modifications to either source or clone with affect them both. Have you looked at using a copy constructor?

Comment: @gunr2171 even though I am saving it to the database right away?

Comment: FYI saving it to the database has nothing to do with cloning it or not.  Sounds like you are conflating those two concepts.  If all you need to do is save a new one without using the ID you could even make a new Session.SaveNew(source) method that ignores the ID.

Comment: So does that mean you don't have control over the `DungeonTreasure` class?

Comment: @chancea thanks!  I thought if I made the new one, with a `null` Id and saved it, it would add the new entry to the Database with a new ID generated by the DB.   `Session.Save` is from a 3rd party library.  It just takes the class and maps and saves it to the database.

Comment: @gunr2171 do you mean something that just copies it property by property?  thanks

Comment: " I thought if I made the new one, with a null Id and saved it, it would add the new entry to the Database" it might, but the source now has had their Id clobbered.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Oh I see what you mean.  Thanks.